# Sorting double arrays into ascending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to sort a Double Array into ascending order manually. The problem I'm having is that the output only lists the 1st smallest value at the top (which is correct), but lists the rest of the values given as 0.0. (The values range from -5 to +20).  Below is my coding attempt at sorting. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
             int index; 
             double temp;

             for(index = 0; index < x.length; index++)
               { 
                 for(int j = 0; j < x.length - 1; j++)
                    {
                       if(x[j + 1] < x[j])
                          {
                             temp = x[j + 1];
                             x[j + 1] = x[j];
                             x[j] = temp;  
                           }
                      }
                }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `Arrays.sort`? It's implementation will perform much better than the one you have come up with.

Comment: Your implementation of bubble sort is almost right. Could you post your complete program. May be you messed up your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s almost bubblesort you got there. try this :

```
 public static void sort(int[] x) {
  boolean sorted=true;
  int temp;

  while (sorted){
     sorted = false;
     for (int i=0; i < x.length-1; i++) 
        if (x[i] > x[i+1]) {                      
           temp       = x[i];
           x[i]       = x[i+1];
           x[i+1]     = temp;
           sorted = true;
        }          
  }
```

}

But Collin is right. You are better off with Arrays.sort.

Comment: I understand this logic better than my For loop, but I get the same results as before. I'm reading the values from a file. And I tried the Arrays.sort (Arrays.sort(x);) but that resulted in something more weird, it listed the smallest value, followed by a bunch of 0.0, then the correct listing of values, in order...

Comment: If Arrays.sort(x) gave you a bunch of 0.0, then most probably you have a bunch of them in your array. I suspect the error is in the input, not in the sorting code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.sort(x)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) from the `java.util` package to sort your array.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need to compare x[index] with x[j]:

```
for (int index = 0; index < x.length - 1; index++) {
  for (int j = index + 1; j < x.length; j++) {
    if (x[j] < x[index]) {
      temp = x[j];
      x[j] = x[index];
      x[index] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried the modified code, but I get the same results as before, 0.0 listed as everything else. I'm reading the values from a file. Any idea why?